# I am getting a reference error using coffescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to call a handleResponse function and its stating that it is undefined. I cant seem to figure it out as they are in the same $document.ready function.

```
jQuery ->
handleResponse(response) ->
    if (response.status_code == 201)
        fundingInstrument = response.cards != null ? response.cards[0] 
        jQuery.post("models/Tablecharge", 
            uri : fundingInstrument.href,
            (r) ->
                if (r.status == 201) 
                    redirect_to @table
                else
                    render 'new'
        )
$('#cc-submit').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    payload = 
    name: $('#cc-name').val()
    number: $('#cc-number').val(),
    expiration_month: $('#cc-ex-month').val(),
    expiration_year: $('#cc-ex-year').val(),
    cvv: $('#ex-cvv').val(),

balanced.card.create(payload, handleResponse())
```

Comment: thanks for the edit was having problems with that

Comment: indentation matters in CoffeeScript (that's one of the issues with it), so your first two lines are suspect (the second line probably is meant to be indented under the first?).

Comment: no problem...is the code all nested under `jQuery ->`? Looks like everything is at the same level, but it might just be the formatting that needs fixing.

Comment: ya everything is nested under jQuery. its all suppose to fire on one $document.ready

Comment: yea the real code is indented at the correct levels i believe.

Comment: ive revised the code to its actual form:

Comment: do you guys have any idea??

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
balanced.card.create(payload, handleResponse)
```

rather than

```
balanced.card.create(payload, handleResponse())
```

Comment: yea I was trying that earlier. it is still giving me the error?

Comment: @adminbanks The _same_ error? Could you provide the complete error message as part of your question.